# How do I load data from another lua file?

Tags: lua

I have a main lua file app.lua , and in that app I have a button to "load data" in.
NOTE: LUA 5.1 not 5.2

The data file is a lua file as well with tables in it.

```lua
data1 = {
  {a,b,c},
  {1,2,3}
}
data2 = {
  {d,e,f}
}
```

The goal was to make those tables available to the app anytime I choose to load the file.

I tried the example from the lua site

```lua
    function dofile (filename)
      local f = assert(loadfile(filename))
      return f()
    end
```

but f() is just printing a massive string. I can't seem to access f.data1[1] for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you're loading is not a data table. That's a piece of code, anonymous function that is executable. You run that code in `return f()` statement.

But see what that code does - it doesn't return anything. Instead it assigns two global variables, `data1` and `data2`. You can access those as `data1[1]` for example.

You could `return` the data in the file being loaded, that way it wouldn't pollute the global environment, and probably will look like you imagined it to be:

```
return {
  data1 = { {a,b,c}, {1,2,3} },
  data2 = { d,e,f}
}
```

And in other file:

```
local f = assert(loadfile(filename))
my_data = f()
print(my_data.data1[1][1])
```

Comment: So if I'm setting that return data to my_data , in that new structure for the return file (which is code, that makes sense) am I able to update that return structure ? say update data1 after I've read it in?

Comment: @SudoGaron Yes, that's an updatable data.  A table.